# UICollectionView constraints doesn't allow to scroll

Tags: objective-c, scroll, storyboard, uicollectionview, constraints

I'm expecting an issue with my `UICollectionView`, basicallly when I clear the constraints it scrolls perfectly though I can't reach the bottom (but that's another day's matter), however the width is way too big, I only see the left half of my `UICollectionView`.

Now, when I set my `constraints` to make it fit the screen, it won't scroll anymore. Even the `UIRefreshControl` isn't triggered.

I ran out of ideas, does somebody have a clue? or a solution?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**
It doesn't scroll though it bounces...

Comment: How many items and section do you return from numberOfSectionsInCollectionView and numberOfItemsInSection delegate methods? I thought that you may confuse between them but this is just guess.

Comment: No I don't confuse them, actually the UICollectionView itself is all right. It's only the way it appears on the screen. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it:
Deleted my `UIViewController` from `StoryBoard` and created it again…

Looks like there's no proper solution though.

Answer (score 0):

By checking the box bounce vertically , fixed my problem.

[image]